# How to specify null date in a query for MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to check a condition on date whether a datecolumn of a table is in range of another two sets of date from other table..

First Table :

```
1. id
2. name
3. date
```

Second table ;

```
1. id
.
.
.
.
17 : Start Date
18 : End Date
```

I have to check whether the `date` field of first table is in range of `Start Date` and `End Date` of second table.

e.g.

```
t1.date>= t2.Start Date and t1.date <= t2.End Date
```

Problem is that, there are some row where `t2` is null..
if it is `null`, then second condition return `true`.

**First Case**

```
 t1.date = 26-Nov-2011
 t2.Start Date = 25-Nov-2011
 t2.End Date  = 27-Nov-2012
 *Passed*
```

**SECOND Case**

```
 t1.date = 26-Nov-2011
 t2.Start Date = 25-Nov-2011
 t2.End Date  = 25-Nov-2011

  *FAILED*
```

**THIRD CASE**

```
 t1.date = 26-Nov-2011
 t2.Start Date = 27-Nov-2011
 t2.End Date  = 27-Nov-2011

  *FAILED*
```

**FOURTH CASE**

```
 t1.date = 26-Nov-2011
 t2.Start Date = 25-Nov-2011
 t2.End Date  = null

  *Passed*
```

Please help.

Comment: Use the `BETWEEN` statement instead of `>= AND <=` for starters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically, you want to treat the case when there is no end date as an "ongoing" case, so, if the first condition is true it should be true. Basically the condition is met if:

1. The date is after or on the start date AND
2. a. The date is before or on the end date OR
   b. There is no end date

Now it's easy to do the SQL:

```
(t1.date>= t2.StartDate) and ((t1.date <= t2.EndDate) or (t2.EndDate is null))
```

Note that you can get similar results using `between` and `isnull`, but as far as I'm concerned, it's much clearer if the conditions are self-explanatory, and I can read them as plaintext.

---

(Old answer, under the assumption that the whole `t2` row is null, as from a left join)

You can just add a condition that the second row is not null, i.e. that the fields `t2.StartDate` and `t2.EndDate` are not null

```
(t1.date>= t2.Start Date and t1.date <= t2.End Date and t2.End Date is not null)
```

Comment: In the above solution, if End Date is null, then the statement return false.. but, it should return true if the first condition is true.

Comment: That is different from what is said in the question. It's implied that the whole `t2` row is null, as from a left join. Please edit the question and clarify the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for you to use  [IS NOT NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null)

then it would look something like this

```
(t1.date BETWEEN t2.Start Date and t2.End Date AND t2.End Date IS NOT NULL)
```

and btw you shouldn't use spaces in your columnnames, use endDate or end_date instead (i prefer endDate)

Comment: In the above solution, if End Date is null, then the statement return false.. but, it should return true if the first condition is true.

Comment: if end date is null the first will still give null, else you must specifie what you mean a bit more